DESeq2 with PC as covariate
I am running DESeq2 for RNA-seq data that has multiple co-variates. below is my sampleTable (the actual table is longer 100 controls and 20 treatment):
condition   age sex     PC1         PC2
control     47  Female  -0.0048629  -0.0034097
control     94  Male    -0.0050488  -0.0033437
treatment   21  Male    -0.0047282  -0.0017674
treatment   47  Female  -0.0046477  -0.00082367

I want to use population-based PCs as covariates. below is the model:
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = dfinput0,
                              colData = sampleTable,
                              design= ~ age+sex+ condition + PC1 + PC2)

It give me the error:
Error in checkFullRank(modelMatrix) :    the model matrix is not full
rank, so the model cannot be fit as specified.   One or more variables or interaction terms in the design formula are linear   combinations of the others and must be removed.

The model works if the design is design= ~ age+sex+ condition or design= ~ sex+ condition + PC1)
But when I add two numerical covariates (such as age+PC1 or PC1+PC2) it gives me this error.
I don't see how age and PC1 are linear combination of each others. Any input how to solve this issue?

Those PC values are small compared to what I see in bulk RNASeq projects.  When I have a strong PC1, the values range from -40 to 40, a PC1 that is a smaller % of the overall variance -20 to 20.  There might not be much point in making use of such meaningless PC1 values.

If this error is happening on the small subset, it'll presumably be because age == 47 cannot be separated from sex == female. You should show a larger subset of the table that doesn't demonstrate linear dependence.
Or better, given that it seems to have issues with linear combinations of PC1 and PC2, plot out PC1 vs PC2 on a scatter plot; if they form a line, then that supports DESeq2's assessment, and at least one of them should be excluded.

That won't be a problem if age is being treated as a number, which if it works with age alone, it probably is.

Yes, it's a weird error given the known metadata and testing that's been done
